# Yet or still in this context?

Tags: word-choice

> 1. The study suggested that there is only an emerging environmental activism in
>    the country, which seems to be **still** true/the case after more than 2 decades
>    since the study was published.

> 2. The study suggested that there is only an emerging environmental activism in
>    the country, which seems to be **yet** true/the case after more than 2 decades
>    since the study was published.

Are both correct?

Comment: I'm not liking the pair **after...since** or the word order. Maybe => there **was** only an emerging environmental activism in the country, **and** still seems to be true more than two decades since the study was published.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Why don’t you like that. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Should I always avoid the ‘after…since’ structure?

Comment: After and since usually do the same job.

Answer (score 3):

'which seems to be still true' could be correct
'which seems to remain accurate' might be better

--these phrases seem more brief, simple, and direct for academic or business writing
-- but this also depends on word overuse and the tone of the whole piece of writing

Comment: This doesn't answer the question by just suggesting alternatives.